# mBJ-LDA band structure calculation using VASP

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, band-structure, k-points

I tried to create a band structure with the mBJ-LDA method using VASP. I found information that the `KPOINTS` file should be created according to the "0-weight (Fake) SC procedure" (as for HSE).

I have a problem because when I approach the $\mathbf{k}$-points corresponding to the second block, I get a structure in which only the points from the second block are contained, not the path between them. How can I increase the accuracy of the mapping of the band structure?
Thank you for your help, it's very important to me.

[image]

Comment: +1. Thanks for asking here, and we hope to see much more of you! Thank you for taking ProfM's advice and asking this as a separate question rather than trying to ask it in a comment to someone else's question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here I will take [Mg3Sb2 from Materials Project](https://www.materialsproject.org/materials/mp-2646/) as an example to demonstrate the bandstructure calculation flow with the MBJ method.

- (I) structure relaxation
- (II) PBE band calculation based on the relaxed structure

  - (a) self-consistent (SCF) calculation [10_scf_cal].
  - (b) band calculation based on converged charge density at (II-a) [11_band_cal].
  - (c) read and plot EIGENVALUE.

[image]

- (III) MBJ band calculation based on step (II).

  - (a) PBE SCF calculation with zero weight k-points.

    #### HOW TO WRITE KPOINTS

    ```
     (1) Copy the IBZKPT at step (II-a) into KPOINTS
     (2) Find all k-points from OUTCAR at step (II-b) and add to the KPOINTS with zero weight.
    ```

    #### INCAR

    ```
     ISTART=0
     ICHARG=2
     ENCUT=400
     EDIFF=1E-6
     NELM=300
     ISMEAR=-5
     IALGO=38
    ```
  - (b) MBJ SCF calculation with zero weight k-points.

    #### INCAR

    ```
     ### Read PBE wavefunction
     ISTART=1
     ICHARG=0
     ENCUT=400
     EDIFF=1E-6
     NELM=300
     ISMEAR=-5

     ###MBJ:
     METAGGA=MBJ
     LASPH=.TRUE.
     LMAXMIX=4
     GGA=CA
     #CMBJ=XXX
    ```
  - (c) read and plot the EIGENVALE with zero weight k-point.
    [image]
- PS: all related input files can be accessed through this link: https://github.com/Kohn-X/MBJ_cal

Comment: could you also please provide us with the INCAR settings during this procedure ?

Comment: @ChiKou Later I will add the INCAR file.

Comment: @ChiKou All related input cards have been attached.

Comment: @ChiKou I have detailed my answer again.

Comment: I'll try to repeat it soon and come back to you with the results

Comment: @ChiKou All input files have been attached: https://github.com/Kohn-X/MBJ_cal

Comment: Hi @Jack, I have currently started working using mBJ-LDA calculation and I am using the exact procedure that you have described. Could you please shed some light on how this is different than TB-mBJ. I am a bit confused some time people use Tran Blaha modified mBJ and modified BJ exchangeably.

Answer (score 9):

If you give the explicit points in the KPOINTS file in VASP for a band structure calculation, for example as required for hybrid functionals, the bands will only be calculated at the explicit $\mathbf{k}$-points you list. For example, if you have a cubic cell and want the path between $\Gamma$ at $(0,0,0)$ and X at $(0.5,0,0)$, then simply writing:

$$
0.0 \,\, 0.0 \,\, 0.0 \\
0.5 \,\, 0.0 \,\, 0.0
$$

in your KPOINTS file will calculate the bands at these two points, but not at the $\mathbf{k}$-points in between. To get more $\mathbf{k}$-points between these two points, you need to *explicitly* include them in your list. For example, to include five points when going from $\Gamma$ to X in the cubic cell you should write:

$$
0.0 \,\, 0.0 \,\, 0.0 \\
0.1 \,\, 0.0 \,\, 0.0 \\
0.2 \,\, 0.0 \,\, 0.0 \\
0.3 \,\, 0.0 \,\, 0.0 \\
0.4 \,\, 0.0 \,\, 0.0 \\
0.5 \,\, 0.0 \,\, 0.0
$$

This will calculate the bands at each of these points. For finer $\mathbf{k}$-point sampling, you simply need to increase the number of divisions between the path end-points.

If you are not using a hybrid functional, then you can use the "Line-mode" in the KPOINTS file where you only need to specify the end points of the path and VASP automatically calculates the bands at the extra points between the end points.

Comment: I think this is not an easy job to prepare the KPOINTS file for the hybrid calculations. I still doubt how can we prepare this file for some different K-points, like (0.0 0 0) to 0.3333, 0.5 0.5). Can we use vaspkit for it? some people use these points from OUTCAR of fake-scf calculations. Please generalize your answer so that we can learn it more.

Comment: I do not understand why you mentioned GGA=CA in III(b) while you have provided POTCAR for PBE. Can you please explain it a bit more?